# Is it safe to make SqlConnection in a DAL class ThreadLocal?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, multithreading, sqlconnection

I have the following DAL class hierarchy (partially shown), which I use for abstracting data access to the database. I would like to use it in a thread-safe manner:

```
public class DbAdapter : IDbAdapter, IDisposable
{
    private SqlConnection _conn;
    private readonly string _connString;

    protected DbAdapter(string connString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connString))
            throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null, empty or whitespace", nameof(connString));
        _connString = connString;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        CloseConnection();
    }

    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {

        if (_conn == null || _conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            _conn = new SqlConnection(_connString);
        else if (_conn.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
        {
            _conn.Close();
            _conn.Open();
        }
        return _conn;
    }

    public void CloseConnection()
    {
        if (_conn != null && _conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _conn.Close();
        _conn = null;
    }

    public SqlCommand GetCommand(string query, SqlTransaction transaction)
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand
        {
            Connection = transaction != null ? transaction.Connection : GetConnection()
        };
        if (transaction != null)
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 500;
        return cmd;
    }
    
    // Omitted other methods
}

public class PersonDba : DbAdapter 
{
    //Omitted 

    public IList<Person> GetPersons(string whereClause, string orderClause, SqlTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        var query = "SELECT Id, Name, PersonId, Birthdate, Modified FROM Persons ";

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(whereClause))
            query += whereClause;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderClause))
            query += orderClause;

        IList<Person> result = new List<Person>();

        var sqlCmd = GetCommand(query, transaction);
        using (var reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var person = new Person
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Id")),
                    PersonId = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("PersonId")),
                    Name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Name")),
                    Birthdate = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Birthdate")),
                    LastModified = reader.GetDateTime(reader.GetOrdinal("Modified"))
                };
                result.Add(person);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Typically, I inject a single instance of `PersonDba` into other classes, which contain multi-threaded code. In order to avoid locking around all access to that single instance within dependant code, I am thinking of making the SQLConnection `DbAdapter._conn` of type `ThreadLocal<SqlConnection>` (see [ThreadLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=netcore-3.1)). Would that be enough to ensure using instances of this class is thread-safe?

Comment: This is a bad abstraction because you're forcing consumers to construct `where` clauses as strings, which means that they can't use the most appropriate way of avoiding SQL injection issues - parameters.

Comment: That's true. It's a legacy code problem, which I manage in upper layers. Nonetheless, this is not the point of the question.

Comment: [You shouldn't share a `SqlConnection` across threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21775057/585968).

Comment: The question you linked deals with something different. In my question I am NOT willing to share the SqlConnection across threads. On the contrary, I want to make it ThreadLocal, which gives every thread its own value.

Comment: You have a larger design problem.  _Each thread should have it's own repo object and subsequent database connection_.  Your `PersonDba` and base class is a strange way to do a repo pattern

Comment: Thought of that too. It would require refactoring for example to inject a PersonDbaFactory instead, which gives every spawned thread its instance. But, once again, I'm specifically asking whether making the instance variable `_conn` ThreadLocal would solve the problem

Comment: That's why these are _comments_ and not _answers_

Comment: Is it possible to use the [`ExecuteReaderAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync) instead of the `ExecuteReader` in the future, or we can assume that your data access layer will remain synchronous forever?

Comment: Yes, @TheodorZoulias, it's possible

Comment: This is mostly subjective, but I would *strongly advise against this*, not least because it won't work at all with `async`, where you can be jumping all over the place in terms of threads. OK, you can side-step that by using async-local or the execution-context to store the ambient data, but it would *still* be a very bad idea. IMO: pass it in explicitly, like you are with the transaction (in fact, since a transaction and connection are deeply connected, passing them in different ways should be a huge red flag)

Comment: Sure, you can make it thread-local. Strongly consider biting the bullet and refactoring this stuff, though -- a first start could be to make `CloseConnection`/`GetCommand` accept it as a parameter, and start rewriting callers up the chain to pass the connection they got. This can then be easily extended to make them use proper `using` patterns. This design is already broken; adding thread-local storage is just going to make things more confusing and unreliable, not less.

Comment: Side note: you're doing a lot of work here that tools like "Dapper" could do for you much more simply; also - a where/order-by clause as a string is just asking for SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to keep open the possibility of making your DAL asynchronous in the future, by using the [`ExecuteReaderAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync) instead of the `ExecuteReader`, then converting the field `_conn` of the class `DbAdapter` to `ThreadLocal<SqlConnection>` is not safe. The reason is that after awaiting the asynchronous request, the asynchronous workflow will most probably continue on another `ThreadPool` thread. So the wrong connection will be closed, and some other unrelated concurrent data access operation may be interrupted and aborted.

Comment: I am considering a *non-static* ThreadLocal<SqlTransaction> _conn variable. Also, currently the code is synchronous, could as well stay so, if thread-safe execution can be guaranteed in consuming classes.

Comment: @Bahaa If you are OK with being constrained in the synchronous model forever, then the `ThreadLocal<SqlConnection>` is safe. Yes, making it static doesn't make sense, because you may want to maintain multiple connections per thread, for different databases. I'll update my answer.