# Is SqlConnection thread-safe when methods are accessed in parallel by different threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ado.net, thread-safety, sqlclient

I would like to know is a `SqlConnection` object created every time when the method is accessed by multiple threads and also would like to know is this method and the `SqlConnection` class is thread safe.

```
public DataSet GetData( string deptId)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
            "Select * FROM Employee where DeptId='"+deptId+"'",con))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: you have **dangerous** SQL injection going on. You should use proper parameterization, like `where DeptId = @deptId`

Answer (score 1):

The [`SqlConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection) [is not thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731641/sqlconnection-thread-safe), meaning that an instance of this class cannot be used by multiple threads concurrently without synchronization.

Nevertheless the `GetData` method is thread-safe, because each time it is called it creates a separate `SqlConnection` instance. This `SqlConnection` object is used only by the current thread, and is not shared by any other code. Also the `GetData` method has no side-effects. It doesn't alter the state of the contained type in any way. It's the kind of method that is usually declared [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). So you are free to call the `GetData` method from as many threads as you like, concurrently, without using the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement or any other form of synchronization.

It should be noted that there is nothing special with the `SqlConnection` not being thread-safe. The vast majority of the built-in .NET classes are not thread-safe. Non-thread-safety is the default. The few .NET classes that are thread safe, like the collections in the [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent) namespace, are explicitly documented to be so. If you are looking at the documentation of a class and you are not finding anything related to thread-safety, you should assume that the class is not thread-safe.