# If a new instance of collection is created inside a function is it thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I just read in C# collections are not thread safe, what if I create a new collection instance everytime inside a function as a local variable. Is it still not thread safe?

```
public void AddToCollection(int item)
{
    List<int> collection = new List<int>();
    collection.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: "I just read in c# collections are not thread safe" - that is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965734/is-it-safe-to-add-and-remove-items-from-a-list-object

Comment: The same principles apply to the `List<T>` as to the `SqlConnection` in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77385837/is-sql-connection-object-thread-safe-when-method-is-accessed-parallelly-by-diffe "Is SqlConnection object thread safe when method is accessed parallelly by different threads?").

Answer (score 2):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous.

Thread-safe refers to whether an object or method can be accessed by multiple threads simultaneously. In this sense, the answer is **no**, a local `List<T>` is still thread unsafe.

If you're asking, is it safe to have multiple threads calling `AddToCollection` simultaneously? The answer is **yes**, because at any time, this list can only be accessed by this method, and there is no multithreading for it, which is naturally safe.

It should be noted again that if you create multiple threads in this method which access the list, then this list is still unsafe. For instance this is unsafe:

```
public void AddToCollection(int item)
{
    List<int> collection = new List<int>();
    Task.Run(() => collection.Add(item));
    Task.Run(() => collection.Add(item));
}
```